My Fast Forward button will only work once, and wont work again
The Fast Forward button goes forward ten seconds, but it will only do it once
All of this is happening in fast_forward_music. The base of the problem seems to be in the variable current_time never changing. In the function, it adds ten seconds to current_time and creates the variable new_time which changes the position of the music, but when going back through it shows that it doesnt change the current time. I cant tell if its a problem with pygame not getting the time correct, or if I need to make the variable global or what. I have some prints so you can see each variable. Thanks in advance :)
# Now you can increase or decrease the volume here, you can also select multiple songs at once and listen to your favorite songs, delete and add songs as needed.
# Remember only this files *.mp3;*.wav;*.ogg;*.mp4;*.avi;*.mkv;*.flv;*.mov;*.wmv;*.webm

import os
import pygame
from tkinter import Tk, filedialog, messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import Listbox

# Initialize the mixer
pygame.mixer.init()

# Create a Tkinter window to select media files
root = Tk()
root.withdraw()

# Global variables
current_file = ""
playlist = []
current_index = 0
is_playing = False
volume = 0.5  # Default volume

# Function to select a file
def select_file():
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[
        ("Audio/Video Files", "*.mp3;*.wav;*.ogg;*.mp4;*.avi;*.mkv;*.flv;*.mov;*.wmv;*.webm")
    ])
    if file_path:
        add_to_playlist(file_path)

# Function to add a file to the playlist
def add_to_playlist(file_path):
    playlist.append(file_path)
    playlist_box.insert("end", os.path.basename(file_path))

# Function to remove a file from the playlist
def remove_from_playlist():
    selected_index = playlist_box.curselection()
    if selected_index:
        playlist.pop(selected_index[0])
        playlist_box.delete(selected_index)

# Function to clear the playlist
def clear_playlist():
    global current_index
    playlist.clear()
    playlist_box.delete(0, "end")
    stop_music()
    current_index = 0

# Function to play the selected file or playlist
def play_music(file_path=None):
    global current_file, current_index, is_playing

    if not file_path:
        selected_index = playlist_box.curselection()
        if not selected_index:
            messagebox.showinfo("Error", "No file selected.")
            return
        current_index = selected_index[0]
        file_path = playlist[current_index]

    pygame.mixer.music.load(file_path)
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    current_file = file_path
    is_playing = True

    update_status()

# Function to pause/resume the music
def pause_resume_music():
    global is_playing

    if is_playing:
        pygame.mixer.music.pause()
        is_playing = False
    else:
        pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
        is_playing = True

    update_status()

# Function to stop the music
def stop_music():
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    update_status()
    play_pause_button.config(text="Play", command=play_music)

# Function to rewind the music
def rewind_music():
    pygame.mixer.music.rewind()

# Function to fast forward the music
def fast_forward_music(seconds):
    current_time = int(pygame.mixer.music.get_pos() / 1000)
    print(f'get_pos {pygame.mixer.music.get_pos()}, current_time {current_time}, seconds {seconds}' )
    new_time = current_time + seconds
    print(f'New time: {new_time}')
    pygame.mixer.music.set_pos(new_time)
    print(f'New pos: {pygame.mixer.music.get_pos()}')

# Function to set the volume
def set_volume(volume_level):
    global volume
    volume = float(volume_level)
    pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(volume)

# Function to update the status label
def update_status():
    global current_file, current_index, is_playing

    if current_file:
        status_label.config(text=f"Now playing: {os.path.basename(current_file)}")
    else:
        status_label.config(text="")

    if is_playing:
        play_pause_button.config(text="Pause", command=pause_resume_music)
    else:
        play_pause_button.config(text="Resume")

    playlist_box.selection_clear(0, "end")
    playlist_box.selection_set(current_index)

# Main GUI window
window = Tk()
window.title("Media Player")

# Create buttons
select_button = ttk.Button(window, text="Select File", command=select_file)
play_pause_button = ttk.Button(window,text="Play", command=play_music)
stop_button = ttk.Button(window, text="Stop", command=stop_music)
rewind_button = ttk.Button(window, text="Rewind", command=rewind_music)
fast_forward_button = ttk.Button(window, text="Fast Forward", command=lambda: fast_forward_music(10))

# Create playlist controls
playlist_label = ttk.Label(window, text="Playlist")
playlist_box = Listbox(window, selectbackground="#3498db", selectforeground="white")
remove_button = ttk.Button(window, text="Remove", command=remove_from_playlist)
clear_button = ttk.Button(window, text="Clear", command=clear_playlist)

# Create volume control
volume_label = ttk.Label(window, text="Volume")
volume_scale = ttk.Scale(window, from_=0.0, to=1.0, orient="horizontal", command=set_volume)
volume_scale.set(volume)  # Set initial volume value

# Create status label
status_label = ttk.Label(window, text="", anchor="center")

# Position the buttons and widgets
select_button.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
play_pause_button.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
stop_button.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)
rewind_button.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)
fast_forward_button.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)
playlist_label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")
playlist_box.grid(row=2, column=0, rowspan=4, columnspan=5, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="nsew")
remove_button.grid(row=2, column=5, padx=5, pady=10, sticky="w")
clear_button.grid(row=3, column=5, padx=5, pady=10, sticky="w")
volume_label.grid(row=6, column=0, padx=10, pady=5, sticky="w")
volume_scale.grid(row=6, column=1, columnspan=4, padx=10, pady=5, sticky="we")
status_label.grid(row=7, column=0, columnspan=6, padx=10, pady=5, sticky="we")

# Configure grid weights
window.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
window.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

# Start the GUI event loop
window.mainloop()

# Quit the mixer
pygame.mixer.quit()




You have already asked this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78318598/my-fast-forward-button-will-only-work-once-and-wont-work-again. Repeating questions to attract attention is not welcome.

I don't have the means to test this at the moment, but it looks to me like get_pos and set_pos both deal in milliseconds, but new_time is still in seconds.

@Rabbid76 sorry :( its like my second question and im new it wont happen again

new_time is meant to be in seconds. making it into milliseconds makes it go 100x the amount of seconds

Did you add this pygame.display.flip()?

@toyotaSupra It isnt in my code anywhere. From what I can see that only changes the display

I figured out the problem. Basically, get_pos() tells you how long the file has been playing for, not the current place of the file. so when you add ten seconds to it it still sees it as just like 3 seconds in even if you have fast forwarded to 13 seconds later. A way I got around this is with global variables
global add
add = add + 10
current_time = pygame.mixer.music.get_pos() / 1000
new_time = current_time + add
pygame.mixer.music.set_pos(new_time)

after that, make the variable change back to being 0 when a file is played
pygame.mixer.music.play()
add = 0


why do people always give me bad reviews :(
